# Overwrite postgresql onupdate with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Original problem**
I'm using [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) in our project. I registered few event listeners for my model like so.

```
@event.listens_for(Post, 'after_update')
@event.listens_for(Post, 'after_insert')
```

Somewhere else in the code I update the `view_counter` property of my model.

```
post.view_counter += 1
DBSession.flush()
```

Now, since `view_counter` is not something I regard as content update, I want to supress firing of `after_update` event in sqlalchemy for this specific update. Is there a way to do it via ORM or is the only way to just do raw SQL update bypassing ORM entirely?

**EDIT**
After some poking around I realized there is another problem, the property is set by `Postgresql` itself

```
date_last_updated = Column(SA_DateTime, default=DateTime.now, onupdate=DateTime.now, nullable=False, index=True)
```

**Problem**
So the question is, how to update a sqlalchemy model without triggering Postgresql update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to make changes to the decorated function, it should be possible to use the [passed arguments](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) to determine which fields were modified, albeit through a little bit of [a workaround](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState). I'm afraid I haven't been able to test this yet, but I hope it helps!

```py
@event.listens_for(Post, 'after_update', raw=True)
@event.listens_for(Post, 'after_insert', raw=True)
def myfunc(mapper, connection, target):
    # Values have been modified
    if target.session.is_modified(target, include_collections=False):
        # view_counter is the only modified value, the hook can be aborted
        if set(target.dict.keys()) - target.unmodified == {'view_counter'}:
            return
    <...the rest of the function...>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did solve original problem, but I discovered another one, I've updated the question.

Comment: You could replace `onupdate=DateTime.now` with `onupdate=myupdatefunc` and define your own context-aware update function using https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions

Comment: Another option would be to explicitly set the updated_at value to the same value it already has, triggering an "update" of the field should mean that the `onupdate` clause is not executed